# BizTalk Message Assignment "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Byte[]' to 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm currently working on a BizTalk orchestration that uses a Message Assignment Shape to convert an incoming xml message to binary so that it can be stored in a promoted property of the outgoing message.

The message assignment shape expression looks as follows (myXml is variable of type System.Xml.XmlDocument):

```
myXml = ReceiveMessage;
SendMessage.Payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myXml.OuterXml);
```

I'm receiveing a design time error of "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Byte[]' to 'System.Byte[]'"

My orchestration looks as follows:

[image]

I've also included the schema for both the incoming and outgoing messages.

Incoming:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:element name="SeleneFTPFile">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Row">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Servicer_x0020_Order_x0020_ID" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Loan_x0020_Number" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Servicer_x0020_Loan_x0020_Number" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Selene_x0020_ID" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="BPO_x0020_Vendor" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Pool" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Order_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Completed_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Review_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Reviewer" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Product" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Product_x0020_Name" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Product_x0020_Name2" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Property_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Size_x0020_Square_x0020_Feet" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Property_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Location" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Location_x0020_View" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Estimate_x0020_of_x0020_Exterior_x0020_Repairs" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Estimate_x0020_of_x0020_Interior_x0020_Repairs" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Occupied" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Currently_x0020_Listed" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="List_x0020_Price" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="List_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Listing_x0020_Agency" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Listing_x0020_Agent" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Listing_x0020_Agent_x0020_Phone_x0020_Number" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="DOM" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Property_x0020_Issue" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Property_x0020_Issue_x0020_Comment" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Confidence_x0020_Score" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Valuation_x0020_Summary" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Current_x0020_REO_x0020_Quick_x0020_Sale_x0020_Value" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Current_x0020_Retail_x0020_Value" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Recommend_x0020_Retail_x0020_List" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Condition_x0020_Grade" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Market_x0020_Grade" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Marketability_x0020_Grade" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Overall_x0020_Risk_x0020_Grade" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Total_x0020_REO_x0020_listing_x0020_in_x0020_Neighborhood" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Total_x0020_Retail_x0020_listing_x0020_in_x0020_Neighborhood" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Total_x0020_REO_x0020_Sales_x0020_in_x0020_Neighborhood_x0020_in_x0020_last_x0020_90_x0020_days" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Total_x0020_Retail_x0020_sales_x0020_in_x0020_Neighborhood_x0020_in_x0020_last_x0020_90_x0020_days" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Neighborhood_x0020_Low_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Neighborhood_x0020_High_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Vandalism_x0020_Risk" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Prop_x0020_Damage_x0020_Flag" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Prop_x0020_Damage_x0020_Desc" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="BPO_x0020_Hyperlink" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Year_x0020_Built" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Last_x0020_Sale_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Last_x0020_Sale_x0020_Price" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_List_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_List_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_List_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Type" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp1_x0020_Sold_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Type" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp2_x0020_Sold_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Type" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Comp_x0020_Type" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Size" type="xs:unsignedShort" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bedroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Bathroom_x0020_Count" type="xs:unsignedByte" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Garage" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Lot_x0020_Size" type="xs:decimal" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Location" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Condition" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Price" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comp3_x0020_Sold_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="BPO_x0020_Date" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="As_x0020_Repaired_x0020_Value" type="xs:unsignedInt" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Outgoing message schema:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:element name="PerformTransformationRequest">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
- <properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
  <property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='PerformTransformationRequest' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Payload' and namespace-uri()='']" /> 
  </properties>
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Version" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Payload" type="xs:base64Binary" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is being caused by the UTF-16 in both schemas.  Take a look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/fd5d9918-c6db-4bcd-a088-78c559427479 and http://romikoderbynew.com/2011/04/09/biztalk-extracting-xsbase64binary/

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, we experienced this error after migrating a BizTalk project from BizTalk 2009 to BizTalk 2010. Deleting the schema project's references to `Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines` and `Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas` made the error go away.